# Getting Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect error while uploading file to another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I have a rails application. Now I have to implement functionality to upload a file to another application.

The given application uses 3-legged oauth for security.
They have following architecture

- First create the file id using POST call (https://www.example.com/org/files)
- Then with the help of above file id, upload file using PUT call (https://www.example.com/files)

I have able to create the FileID. But while making PUT call (uploading file) getting the `Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect` error.

So how can I upload the file in chunk. Here is my sample code for uploading file.

```
file_data = File.open("/home/test/Downloads/RechargeReceipt.pdf") {|io| io.read}
file_data_64 = Base64.encode64(file_data)

access_token.put("/org/files/3156906966",
  { 'Content' => file_data_64 }.to_json,
  {
    'Accept' => 'application/vnd.axiom.v3+json', 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream' 
  }
)
```

I am using rails 4.

Comment: Is SSL certificate of remote host valid?

Comment: @retgoat yes it is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue while passing the body parameters.

```
data = File.read(params[:file].path)
access_token.put("/org/files/#{file_id}",
        data,
        {
          'Accept' => JohnDeere::ACCEPT,
          'Content-Type' => content_type
        }
      )
```